# What does this say?

Tags: translation, books

I need to find out the publication details of a Chinese book. I've taken an image of what I believe is the info box that gives them. Could any kind person please tell me what this says? I'd really like to know the book's title, publisher and publication date.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old book... I translate some basic info for you.

**Title:** ILLUSTRATION OF GREAT ART TRADITION
**Publisher:** Shanghai Publishing Co., Ltd (This company should not exist, but I haven't found the successor so far. The former location is at Room 701, Number 346 Middle Sichuan Road, Shanghai) Refer to this building -- 嘉陵大楼（Jialing Building ）http://j.map.baidu.com/bP3hZ  and  https://www.sohu.com/a/162636510_391475
**Publication date:** Aug, 1951 - Aug, 1952 The First Edition, The First Print.
                  Aug, 1954 The First Edition, The Fourth Print.
**Other reference:** http://www.potomackcompany.com/asp/fullCatalogue.asp?salelot=45+++++++630+&refno=+++32833

https://www.douban.com/note/499800911/

EDIT:

OK, the publisher was 上海出版股份有限公司(Shanghai Publishing Co., Ltd) and was merged into 新文艺出版社 in 1956. And now it is merged into 上海世纪出版集团(Shanghai Century Publishing(Group) Co., Ltd ) according to [Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7%E4%B8%96%E7%BA%AA%E5%87%BA%E7%89%88%E9%9B%86%E5%9B%A2).

Comment: Thank you so much Bruce, that's fantastic! So interesting to read about the building too!

Comment: I'm glad to help!